# Rust `borrow_mut`, `borrow_mut` and move

Tags: rust, move, borrow-checker

My code is

```rust
struct Test<Source>
where
    Source: Iterator<Item = char>,
{
    source: Source,
}

impl<Source: Iterator<Item = char>> Test<Source> {
    fn read(&mut self) {
        while let Some(item) = self.source.next() {
            match item {
                '#' => self.read_head(),
                _ => {}
            }
            println!("Handled char {}", item);
        }
    }

    fn read_head(&mut self) {
        println!("Start read heading");
        let source = self.source.borrow_mut();
        let level = source.take_while(|&char| char == '#').count();
        println!("Done, level is {}", level);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let str = "##### Hello World".to_string();
    let str = str.chars().into_iter();
    let mut test = Test { source: str };
    test.read();
}
```

It works good. But in this line:

```rust
let source = self.source.borrow_mut();
```

If changes `borrow_mut` to `borrow`, will produce the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*source` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |         let level = source.take_while(|&char| char == '#').count();
   |                     ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*source` has type `Source`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So why borrow_mut works but borrow not. I don't have a clear understanding about relation between `move` and `borrow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why `borrow_mut` works but `borrow` not.

Because [there is an implementation of `Iterator` for exclusive references to iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13):

```rust
impl<'_, I> Iterator for &'_ mut I where I: Iterator + ?Sized
```

This means an exclusive reference to an Iterator *is itself an iterator*, and can be used "as is" (which incidentally is why [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) is a thing, and useful).

> I don't have a clear understanding about relation between `move` and `borrow`.

There isn't one in and of itself, it's just that in this case a mutable reference to an iterator is also an iterator (in its own right), which means it fulfills `take_while`'s requirements to take an iterator by value:

```rust
pub fn take_while<P>(self, predicate: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, P> where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool
```

a shared reference is not so, and thus triggers the error you see.

Comment: Might want to mention that the reason there is an implementation of iterator for mutable references iterators only, is because advancing the iterator requires mutating its state, which is why an immutable borrow fundamentally cannot work.